# How to add my icon with CSS property position:absolute such that it always remains with the password field I am adding it on

Tags: html, css

I am adding a eye icon on top of a password field on my webpage for the "see password" functionality. I am using the CSS property position : absolute. Here is my code :

```
i{
  position: absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:1200px;
 }
```

when I want to view my webpage on a mobile device, I have to shrink down the password field and also change its location. But since the position of eye icon is absolute, the icon does not show up on the password field on the mobile device and shows up somewhere else.

Is there any way I can make the icon stay with the password field?

Comment: Can you give us the html and the css of the input? You probably do not have `position: relative` on your password input

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use relative like that: ?

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```css
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="secret">
              <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap input in a div and set it's `position:relative` and for the icon use below style.

```
.field-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 10px;
  }
```

In this way your icon will be always in its position no matter of screen size.

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```css
.icon-wrap {
    position: relative;
  }
  .field-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <div class="icon-wrap">
  <input
    id="password-field"
    type="password"
    class="form-control"
    name="password"
    value="secret"
  />
  <span
    toggle="#password-field"
    class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"
  ></span>
</div>
```